# How can we have flag type series in navigator for High Stock chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have create 1 sample jsfiddle, where I have 1 flag series. Its displaying flags in chart but showing line plot in navigator series. How can we have flags in navigator?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky3z8v9v/)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Don't share your contact details here.

Comment: Flags in the navigator does not work properly. You can see an issue on github tracker here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6655 You can force the flags to be shown if you set navigatorOptions.type = flags but it does not looks well. http://jsfiddle.net/co8e4d0j/1/